# why does sbt throw error while trying to compile mllib example

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I am trying to compile and run the below example with the steps given at the link

http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/classifiying-documents-using-naive-bayes-on-apache-spark-mllib/

i get the following error while trying to do the same.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /siva/nbais/blog-spark-naive-bayes-reuters-master/project
[warn]  module not found: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /root/.ivy2/local/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/1.6.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-idea-repo: tried
[warn]   http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.3/1.6.0/sbt-idea-1.6.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.3/1.6.0/sbt-idea-1.6.0.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.5.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /root/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.5.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-idea-repo: tried
[warn]   http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.5.0/sbteclipse-plugin-2.5.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.5.0/sbteclipse-plugin-2.5.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.6.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbteclipse:sbteclipse-plugin:2.5.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/siva/nbais/blog-spark-naive-bayes-reuters-master/project/}default-4c8897/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.6.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.5.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt-idea 1.6.0 requires Scala 2.10+ and SBT 0.13+. But your env is Scala 2.9.1 and SBT 0.11.3. Please update them.

Comment: E.g., add/update `build.sbt` with `scalaVersion := "2.10.4"`; add/update `project/build.properties` with `sbt.version=0.13.6`.